# How can sp_blitz help investigate what caused TLog to fill up

Tags: sp-blitz

Non-uncommon scenario:  Something has ran wild and caused the TLog for a patifular Db to fill and everything has stopped.  How can sp_blitz show us some info on what led up to this point? What about sp_whoisactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sp_Blitz doesn't track that kind of thing. A better approach would be [querying LOG_REUSE_WAIT_DESC](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/my-favorite-system-column-log_reuse_wait_desc/).